# Why Cron job stop working after some months

Tags: codeigniter, cron, cron-task

I added cron which visit URL, was working fine.

Syntax of the cron job was this

```
wget -q -O /dev/null "https://test.com/Login/autoreleasereservation" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

this cron job was running after every minute.

Previously it was working fine, but now its not working anymore.

I also contact to hosting and server provider they said, there is no fault from our end.

**Can anybody tell me how can i debug or resolve this issue ?**

**Is there any other way to urn URL in cron job?**

Comment: this is guess-work only, since it is impossible to give an answer with the context you provided in your Q. Anyway in the first place I would check, if your hosting service has changed the php version, if so compare if your code has unsupported functions.

Comment: @Vickel when i direct run my script, it works but using cron job not working

Comment: but it did work before, right? you write *Cron job stop working after some months*, if you have not changed anything in your code, then your service provider must have!

Comment: Yes i did not change anything